# Jboss Service started and then stopped

Tags: windows, jboss, service

I'm attempting to get my Jboss Server running as a windows service using the JbossService.exe, and I had it working until I uninstalled it (with ./JbossService -uninstall JbossService), and now, while it will install and the service will appear in the windows service list, attempting to start it will only yield the error message:

"The JBossService on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the Performance Logs and Alerts service."

If it helps, the command I'm using to install it is:

```
./JBossService.exe -install JBossService "$java_home\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
 -Xmx128m -Xrs -Djava.class.path="$java_home\lib\tools.jar;$jboss_home\bin\run.jar"
 -Duser.timezone="Australia/Sydney" 
 -start "org.jboss.Main" -stop "org.jboss.Main" 
 -method systemExit  -out "$jboss_home\server\default\log\stdout.log"
 -err "$jboss_home\server\default\log\stderr.log" 
 -current "$jboss_home\bin"
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. If more information is required just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Cygwin?  If not, this could be due to the fact that environment variables are referenced using `%%`, not `$`, on Windows.  You might try the following instead:

```
JBossService.exe -install JBossService "%java_home%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
 -Xmx128m -Xrs -Djava.class.path="%java_home%\lib\tools.jar;%jboss_home%\bin\run.jar"
 -Duser.timezone="Australia/Sydney" 
 -start "org.jboss.Main" -stop "org.jboss.Main" 
 -method systemExit  -out "%jboss_home%\server\default\log\stdout.log"
 -err "%jboss_home%\server\default\log\stderr.log" 
 -current "%jboss_home%\bin"
```

Even if you are using Cygwin, the `$` notation still might not work if, for example, these parameters are being stored in the Registry and then read later from the OS (which does not understand Cygwin notation).

Answer (score 0):

While this does have a valid answer, one reason this happened to me recently is because the user the JBoss Windows Service was running as had certain active directory permissions revoked from the server (in this case, administrative-like permissions); it could no longer access certain directories it required in order to process (the Java bin folder, for example).

Once the user the service ran as was added back to the appropriate Windows User Groups, the JBoss Windows Service started with no issues.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, JAVA_HOME was not set. Once I did that, Automatically windows Services started.
 :)